# Jmx file is running on GUI but not showing any result in Listeners

Tags: jmeter

Jmx file is running on GUI but not showing any result in Listeners:
[image: Jmx file is running on GUI but not showing any result in Listeners.]

Comment: Looks like there are no active threads sending request when you took the screenshot. What's the configuration you have in the Thread Group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot you sent, I can see that test is still running (11 sec) and there isn't any requests that got a proper response. What you can do:

- You should check the configuration of your thread group first.
- This problem could be about the response time of your requests. If it takes too long for your services to respond, you will see the request after some time have passed.
- Add a separate request at the beginning of your test script. (For example send a get request for google.com). If you get a response and see the result in your listeners, you can understand that problem is not about JMeter listeners, but your requests.
- Make sure that you haven't add any think time timers in your script.